# Is this on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Here's a question I'm thinking of posting and would like input if it's too subjective, or ways to improve it. Here are the flavors.

A: "What are the most reasoned arguments why Ethereum will not succeed?"

B: "What are the most reasoned arguments why Ethereum will fail?"

C: "What are the most reasoned arguments why Ethereum should be dismissed?"

D: "What are the most reasoned arguments made by sceptics of Ethereum? Which arguments also apply to Bitcoin?"

E: "What are the most reasoned critiques of Ethereum made by Bitcoin experts? And which ones do not apply to Bitcoin?"

F: "What are the most reasoned arguments by Bitcoin experts, why Ethereum will fail?"

I am thinking of using E with this text: "Ethereum has been discussed by Bitcoin experts, for example on IRC such as #bitcoin-wizards. What are the most reasoned critiques of Ethereum made by Bitcoin experts? Which ones apply and do not apply to Bitcoin?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have thought this question, whichever flavour you use, is quite subjective (and bad subjective using the definition in this [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)). "Most reasoned" is quite a subjective thing. You may think things are quite reasoned, but I may disagree.

Comment: I saw removing "most reasoned" worked fine for the question. Thanks